Trace of matrix product involving identity and powers
Suppose we know $\text{Tr}(A)=a$. Is there a closed formula for obtaining
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Tr}(A(A-I)^n),
\end{eqnarray}
for any $n=1,2,...$ and with $I$ being the identity matrix? Such products appear commonly when we have $A\log(A)$ if we expand $\log(A)$ into its series form.
We further assume $A$ to be positive semidefinite matrix.

Maybe assume $A$ is diagonalizable, and analyze the case when $A$ is diagonal first.

Are the entries of $A$ complex numbers ? Or is it a matrix with entries in an arbitrary field ?

$A$ is assumed to have non-negative eigenvalues.

There is no such formula: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = I$ satisfy $\text{Tr}(A) = 2 = \text{Tr}(B)$. Both are also positive semidefinite. But for any $n \geq 1$,
$$\text{Tr}(A(A - I)^n) = 2 \neq 0 = \text{Tr}(B(B - I)^n)$$

Generally speaking, if $A$ is positive definite and has eigenvalues (including multiplicities) $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_m$, then $a = \text{Tr}(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^m \lambda_i$, whereas,
$$\text{Tr}(A(A - I)^n) = \sum_{i = 1}^m \lambda_i(\lambda_i - 1)^n$$
$\lambda_i$ can be any nonnegative number. There’s certainly no reason the sum of $\lambda_i$ should determine $\sum_{i = 1}^m \lambda_i(\lambda_i - 1)^n$.

Thanks for the answer, the question though is not whether by knowing $\text{Tr}(A)=a$ one can automatically determine the trace of the multiplication, but rather whether a closed formula (which is a function of $a$) exists.

@Zarathustra $\text{Tr}(A(A-I)^n)$ is not even a function of $a = \text{Tr}(A)$, as made clear by my answer. Obviously no such closed formula can exist.

Sorry I missed the point, you are right. In principle, $a$ would appear on the RHS but there will be more arbitrary terms that are not directly related to $a$ in any way.

@Zarathustra Indeed, you need to know $\text{Tr}(A^m)$ for more than just $m = 1$.
